# Wordpress: Preload next post images

Tags: jquery, wordpress, preload

As the title says, i would like a nice bit of coding to stick in my functions that pre-loads any images that are attached to the next post.

This means that whilst my users are browsing, they page will load, but it will actually be loading the next page, so when you click-through, the images should already be there and waiting!

Think of it as 'buffering' for image.

Anyone got any thoughts on this?

Cheers!

Comment: It might be worth taking a look at the [Wordpress Stack Exchange site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) for Wordpress-specific help (though people here are more than able to also help, and this **does not** represent a vote-to-close).

Comment: Didn't realise there was a specific area! Next time i will be sure to - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your visitor is on page generated by single.php. You need to put your js in there. You need to do it inside the loop because that is only place where you have post id to work with.
There is only one problem, what is your **next post**? Post that was posted before current or after current? If visitor is going backwards you need to load images from post posted before current.
Anyway you can do something like this (presuming you already have jquery loaded).

**NOTE: you have to put this in the loop**!

```
removed old code
```

Docs for get_adjacent_post() are [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post), you can set post to be in same category, and you can exclude categories.

UPDATE: I made some funny typos so here is good code, tested on my installation of wp, works with custom post types:

```
<?php
    $next_post = get_adjacent_post(false, '', false );// set last param to true if you want post that is chronologically previous
    //for debug
    if(!empty($next_post)){
       echo 'Next post title is: '.$next_post->post_title;
    } else {
        echo 'global $post is not set or no corresponding post exists';
    }
    $args = array('post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_parent' => $next_post->ID);
    $attachments = get_posts($args);
    // print attachments for debug
    echo '<pre>';print_r($attachments);echo '</pre>';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var images = '';
        <?php foreach($attachments as $attachment):
            $mime = $attachment->post_mime_type;
            if($mime == 'image/jpeg' || $mime == 'image/gif' || $mime == 'image/png'): 
        ?>
        images += '<img src="<?php echo $attachment->guid ?>" style="display:none" />';
        <? endif; endforeach; ?>
        if(images != ''){
            $('body').append(images);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Wow - @Ivan Ivanic that looks just about spot-on! Except it does not quite work...

Where would the image that is being pre-loaded be returned to? It seems that the only bit coming back is:

<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        var images = '';

                if(images != ''){

            $(body).append(images);

        }

    });

</script>.

Comment: It would return that if there are no images in next post. Also images have to he added in wp way, images added with <img> tags won't work. There has to be post<->attachment relationship in wp-db. Well it isn't bullet proof. This is basic setup, you will need some debugging to see where it fails. I added some debug in answer.

Comment: I see. I thought that any images set at 'Featured Images' are automatically attached? I use this call to grab the featured images;`<?php
         if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
           the_post_thumbnail('portrait');
          } else {
            echo '<img src="#" alt="Something Went Wrong?" title="Sorry - Something went wrong?" />';
         }
        ?>`             

Is that not the WP way?

Comment: I has some typos in code :/ I wrote $attach*em*nt->post_mime_type; Try new code it should work. I tested this time ;) Also code is a bit ugly the best way would be to not print anything if there are no images in next post, but I leave the refactoring to your amusement :)

Comment: I think it wont work for post_thumbnail because it is defined in wp_postmeta table as _thumbnail_id, and attachments are defined as _wp_attached_file. If you want to preload post_thumbnail, than you can easily alter code to do it. Cheers.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, @Ivan Ivanic! Now returning: `<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var images = '';
                images += '<img src="http:***/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/image.jpg" style="display:none" />';
                if(images != ''){
            jQuery('body').append(images);
        }
    });
</script>`. So that image will be loaded on that page, even though it sits in the JS code?

Comment: It is appended to body at the end, before ending </body> tag. It will load, but since it *display* property is set to *none* it will not change the flow of page, which is I assume you want.

Comment: Yeah, i realise the display part, but i can't see the image line; `<img src="http:***/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/image.jpg" style="display:none" />` outside of the js code itself. Is that correct?

Comment: And how are you looking? Source of page, or Firebug/Developer Tools?

Comment: This is from chrome dev tools: http://efekat.com/public/Selection_003.png Don't forget to accept answer as right ;)

Comment: What a legend :) Must have overlooked that! Thank you VERY much! :D

Comment: I know, right! Just gets better and better and the fact that i can pose what is really a hard question (at least in my eyes) and have a fully-functional answer back in less than 24 hours is unreal... Thanks again